# Redux state mutation

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Why does react think I am mutating state when clearly I am passing a new object? Am I missing something?
This is my reducer to adding a question on a quiz object within an array of quizzes.

```
case types.UPDATE_QUESTION_SUCCESS: {
  let quizContext = state.filter(quiz => quiz.id === action.quizId);
  let filteredQuestions = quizContext[0].questions.filter(question => 
    question.questionId !== action.question.questionId
  );
  filteredQuestions.push(action.question);
  quizContext[0].questions = filteredQuestions;
  let quiz = quizContext[0];
  return [...state.filter(quiz => quiz.id !== action.quizId), Object.assign({}, quiz)];
}
```

Error:

```
Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path `quizes.4.questions.1`. This may cause incorrect behavior. (http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)
```

Comment: Please post the whole reducer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since you only care about `quizContext[0]`, `filter` is overkill.
Just do:

```
const quiz = state.find(quiz => quiz.id === action.quizId);
```

to achieve the same result.

I don't want to do too much code review here but one more thing. You do use `let` even though you should use `const` all the time. `const` just means you can't reassign the variable you can still mutate it.

Then you filter the questions add one and then add it back to the quiz you just found.

The `quizContext[0].questions =` is the issue because even though your objects are now in a new array they're still the same objects so if you mutate them you mutate the state.

```
const quiz = Object.assign({}, state.find(quiz => quiz.id === action.quizId));
```

So rewriting the complete thing you'd end up with something like this:

```
case types.UPDATE_QUESTION_SUCCESS:
{
  const quiz = Object.assign({}, state.find(quiz => quiz.id === action.quizId));
  quiz.questions = quiz.questions.filter(question =>
    question.questionId !== action.question.questionId
  );
  quiz.questions.push(action.question);
  return [...state.filter(quiz => quiz.id !== action.quizId), quiz];
}
```

But keep in mind that most of the time you don't wan't to filter data in your reducer at all. Instead I'd recommend to use [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) so that you can compute derived data from the data in your store.

Comment: `Object.assign` does a shallow merge, when the state has a nested structure this might lead to further mutation as the references beyond the first level deep are actually references to the old state.

Comment: @sasidhar that's wouldn't have an effect in this case and in redux if you have a deeply nested structure, you'd add new reducers which handle the depth - everything else would be just bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the state as per your reducer. When you are using filter function the objects that are passed to the filter are references of the original object, you are not doing a deepCopy here. And this line `filterQuestions.push(action.question)` is actually mutating the state.

Try this instead:
`let quizContext = cloneDeep(state.filter(quiz => quiz.id === action.quizId));`

Although there might be a more elegant solution out there, this is where you are going wrong. The filtered objects being returned are references into the original array, but not new objects. So you end up mutating the original objects in the state.

--More clarification--

`cloneDeep` is a lodash function and if you are using `Object.assign` it is going to do only a shallow merge, but not a deep merge. So when the state is mutated at a deeper level the references are still of the original object there by mutating the original state

--EDIT 2--

as noted by mash the line that is mutating your state is `quizContext[0].questions = filteredQuestions;` and use `Object.assign` if you are sure you don't have a nested state in which case more reducers are in order

Comment: The push itself does not mutate the state! cloneDeep it is not a function nor is it good practice or appropriate as you already noticed in this case.

Comment: @mash The push function is the one that is causing the mutation. No? The reference it has is into the original object within the old state so the push actually pushes to the original object, so I didn't get what you meant when you said "push itself does not mutate the state!" ?

Comment: no it doesn't as the ECMA-262 states `filter does not directly mutate the object on which it is called but the object may be mutated by the calls to callbackfn.` so pushing to the new array will only add an item to the new array not to `quizContext[0].questions`. The mutation occurs once he reassigns it.

Comment: `filter` does not mutate the state, but the references returned by filter still have the ability to mutate the state, which is what `push` does in this case. See this https://jsfiddle.net/ajmn8prn/. Also see the edits in my answer

Comment: the push you're arguing about is more like a [push](https://jsfiddle.net/ajmn8prn/1/) and not accessing element zero and setting a new property. That's an entirely different conversation.